# Beamer template customization: logo, headline, and footline

Tags: beamer, header-footer, positioning

I am using the `Luebeck` template for a `beamer` presentation and am encountering some issues with customization.

1. I would like to move the **logo** to the **top right corner** (in the `headline`) in order for it to be out of the way for the content of each frames and be visible.
2. I would like to insert the **date** (short date) in the **bottom left corner** (in the `footline`), aligned left. I found a solution to insert the page number to the bottom right corner but I can not seem to be able to replicate it for the left part.

#### Bonus questions

1. Could it be possible to add two different logo ; the first one in the top left corner, the second one in the top right corner?
2. Is it possible to remove the `headline` (the contents) in the titlepage? Would it be a bad idea?

#### Expected

Had to remove image to be able to post those in the Edit section below.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Packages
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Parameters
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Luebeck}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
% ToC
\AtBeginSection[] {
  \begin{frame}{Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
% Pagination
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Infos
\title[Short title]{Title}
\subtitle[Short subtitle]{Subtitle}
\author[Short Author]{Author}
\date[Short date]{Date}
\institute[Short Institute]{Institute}
\logo{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo.png}}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Document
\begin{document}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Titlepage
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage{}
\end{frame}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ToC
\begin{frame}{Contents}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Content
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{frame}{First subsection}
  \dots
\end{frame}

\subsection{Second subsection}
\begin{frame}{Second subsection}
  \dots
\end{frame}

\section{Second section}
\section{Third section}
\section{Fourth section}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Fin
\end{document}
```

---

## Edit

The solution proposed by @samcarter works great except for a small offset on the top right corner image.

Indeed a small space is inserted before the image and it expands depending on the subsections of the active section.

[image]
[image]

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Packages
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Parameters
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Luebeck}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
% ToC
\AtBeginSection[] {
  \begin{frame}{Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
% Headline
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\includegraphics[height=\@tempdimb]{logo-1.png}\hfill\insertsectionnavigation{.3\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\hfill\includegraphics[height=\@tempdimb]{logo-2.png}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
% Footline
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortdate \hfill \insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle \hfill \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Infos
\title[Short title]{Title}
\subtitle[Short subtitle]{Subtitle}
\author[Short Author]{Author}
\date[Short date]{Date}
\institute[Short Institute]{Institute}
% \logo{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo.png}}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Document
\begin{document}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Titlepage
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage{}
\end{frame}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ToC
\begin{frame}{Contents}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Content
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{frame}{First subsection}
  \dots
\end{frame}

\subsection{Second subsection}
\begin{frame}{Second subsection}
  \dots
\end{frame}

\section{Second section}
\section{Third section}
\section{Fourth section}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Fin
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Packages
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Parameters
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Luebeck}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
% ToC
\AtBeginSection[] {
  \begin{frame}{Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
% Headline
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\includegraphics[height=\@tempdimb]{example-image}\hfill\insertsectionnavigation{.3\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\hfill\includegraphics[height=\@tempdimb]{example-image}\vfil}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%    
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
% Footline
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortdate \hfill \insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle \hfill \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Infos
\title[Short title]{Title}
\subtitle[Short subtitle]{Subtitle}
\author[Short Author]{Author}
\date[Short date]{Date}
\institute[Short Institute]{Institute}
% \logo{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo.png}}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Document
\begin{document}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Titlepage
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage{}
\end{frame}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ToC
\begin{frame}{Contents}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Content
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{frame}{First subsection}
  \dots
\end{frame}

\subsection{Second subsection}
\begin{frame}{Second subsection}
  \dots
\end{frame}

\section{Second section}
\section{Third section}
\section{Fourth section}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Fin
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great but I noticed a small quirk in regard to the top right image. It seems that its top position is affected by the subsections of the current section, thus being pushed to the bottom of the header and disappearing beneath the frame.
Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: @Florian maybe this can be repaired, can you edit your question and include an example?

Comment: I added a section at the end of my post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Florian Can you test my edited answer?