# How to disable headline/footline on title page of beamer presentation in template?

Tags: beamer, themes

I want to build a template for beamer as there need to build quite some presentations with it. I'm quite far but one point causes trouble for me at the moment:

I want the fooline not to be present on the titlepage. I can reach that by putting `[plain]` to the corresponding `frame` (see MWE below).

If possible I would prefer the template to handle this automatically. I tried things like

```
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{\setbeamertemplate{footline}{} ...}
```

but this seems not to have any effect. I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18828/how-to-remove-footline-on-the-title-page-of-beamer-slides) but I want to avoid any constructs in the main presentation file. In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330825/7166) the headline in this case is removed but I think this just sifted out of the current page using spacings added.

So the way to go seems to be adding `plain` or the comparison with the frame number. The first page will be by 80% the title page but there might be mini-presentations that do not have any title page at all. I had to create some of these recently each having only two or three frames with a set of overlays.

Is there any better way to avoid typesetting the fooltline **within the template** on the title page only? I would like to write something like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{MyTheme}

\begin{document}
\titlepage % or not if it is only a few frames

%...

\end{document}
```

Here comes an MWE of my solution so far:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% Default footline for whole presentation
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{My footline}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{Here comes my title page}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}%[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Regular frame
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using a dedicated page style.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\title{My Presentation}
\author{Me}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@navigation@titlepage{%
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \@nameuse{ps@navigation}}
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\thispagestyle{navigation@titlepage}}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{My Frametitle}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```